# Remove special character from end of string

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to remove special characters from the end of a string.

Input:

```
looking for Oracle help ~(
looking ~! for Oracle help ~( Stack
looking ~! for Oracle help ~( Stack ##
```

Output:

```
looking for Oracle help
looking ~! for Oracle help ~( Stack
looking ~! for Oracle help ~( Stack
```

So I just need to remove non-alphanumeric characters from the end of the string only.

I am looking for Oracle SQL query to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace(str, '[^[:alnum:]]*$') from....
```

where `str` is the input string value. This will remove all the non-alphanumeric characters at the end of `str` (`$` is anchoring at the end; `*` means as many as possible consecutive characters; `[...]` means character matching set, and `^` within the character matching set means negation). By not giving a third argument to `regexp_replace()`, the substring is replaced with nothing (`''`)